# Delete My Gmail Account In My iPad

Tags: ipad, gmail

I wanna give away my old iPad to my kid, and would like to delete my Gmail account from the old iPad.

Questions:

1) Will my Gmail account be totally erased when I delete my Gmail account on my iPad?

2) I have thousands and thousand of contacts in my iPad which is linked to Gmail, I'm afraid if I delete the Gmail account, all contact details will be gone forever.

Thanks and looking forward to your favorable reply.

Comment: I assume you still want to keep that gmail account (on another device). So just disable it on the iPad. Then delete all mail in it. You will still have all the email and Contacts in your gmail account (at Google).

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the Gmail account from the iPad by going to Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars -> Select your Gmail account -> Tap the Delete Account button.

The account will no longer be available on that iPad, but no contacts or email will be deleted from the account at Google, just from the iPad. DO NOT delete the emails and contacts themselves manually, they will be removed from the iPad when you remove the account from it.

Depending on the age of your kid and how much you want to keep him/her from getting access to your emails and contacts, it might also be enough to just disable Mail, Contacts, Calendars and/or Notes from the Gmail account screen instead of removing the entire account. If you do this, just enabling them again will put the email and contacts back on the device.

Answer (score 1):

This option:
-> Mail, Contacts, Calendars -> Select your Gmail account -> Tap the Delete Account button.
Was not available on my device.

I found that the account had only been setup through the Gmail app.  If that is the case, open up the Gmail app and go to "Manage Settings". Long press on the account you would like to remove and it will give you the option to edit.  From there you can delete the account.

I was recovering an iPad for another user and deleted the gmail app.  When I installed Google Drive, it automatically signed in with the old account.  I had to reinstall the Gmail app. After that, I was able to remove the account from "Manage Settings" within the Gmail app.